# Hive SQL. Find most popular value across multiple columns

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have following data:

```
name device operating browser
 A     mob      l       c
 A     mob      l       b
 A     mob      l       b
 A     web      w       b
 B     web      w       c
 B     web      w       c
 B     mob      w       c
 B     web      l       b
```

And I want to find most common values for each name in each column so result will look like this:

```
name device operating browser
 A     mob      l       b
 B     web      w       c
```

How can I achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We aren't a free Codingservice. Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve]. If you got a specific problem to code you have written, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

It might help.
But please attention, sub query is not really good to be used.

```
SELECT
a.name,
(SELECT b.device FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME b WHERE b.name = a.name GROUP BY device ORDER BY COUNT(b.device) DESC LIMIT 1) AS device,
(SELECT c.operating FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME c WHERE c.name = a.name GROUP BY operating ORDER BY COUNT(c.operating) DESC LIMIT 1) AS operating,
(SELECT d.browser FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME d WHERE d.name = a.name GROUP BY browser ORDER BY COUNT(d.browser) DESC LIMIT 1) AS browser
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME AS a
GROUP BY a.name
```

Answer (score 0):

For Hive 0.11+ you could use window function like `rank`:

```
select name, device, operating, browser
from (
  select *, rank() over (partition by name order by cnt desc) as rnk
  from (
    select name, device, operating, browser, count(*) as cnt
    from yourtable
    group by name, device, operating, browser
  ) t
) t
where rnk = 1
```

Step by step:

1. count occurences of the same row values
2. rank them over the count with highest for each name on top
3. filter only those that have highest count

Note: if there's a tie within particular name, it would return all the rows with the same count number for them.